# Multi website multi currency setup

Tags: magento-1.9, multi-website

I want to set up multiple magento websites with multiple currencies

1. website A with currency INR
2. website B with currecny USD

Products in each website should have prices which are not dependent on the other website.

1. website A - product A - INR 100
2. website B - product A - USD 15

I have changed the currency scope to website but while adding the product the default currency in still being shown as INR.

Can some one please tell me how this can be done in magento 1.9

Answer (score 2):

You can set up 2 websites with 2 currencies, in order to do this,

> Go to **System >> Configuration >> Currency setup** (Don't forget to select the scope )
>
> Select the currencies allowed for that store
>
> Select the default currency for that store
>
> Go to **System >> Manage Currency >> Rates and import** the live currency rate.
>
> Flush your cache and your websites now have different currencies.

Regarding setting up different price on different websites:

You can change the product price scope to Website by following below steps:

> **Go to System >> Configuration >> Catalog >> Price**
> **Change the catalog Price scope to "Website"**

Comment: I am trying to create multi-website locally (Centos - Nginx) But getting error in Nginx configuration. Any help thanks https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/315027/57334 @Nidheesh

Answer (score 2):

Go to **System-Configuration-Catalog-Catalog-Price**

Switch *Catalog price scope* to *Website*, now you can set different price per product for each website

Go to **System-Configuration-Currency setup**

Change website scope, now you can set default currency and display currency for each website