# Magento 2.3 - LEMP Localhost - How to configure Nginx for Multi-Website store on Localhost (Centos 7)

Tags: nginx, magento2.3.4, multi-website, centos, linux

Where is an error in my following steps for creating Multi Website Store ::

Steps :-

1. Main website Path : usr/share/nginx/html/giri

   - Contains all magento files
   - Configuration in nginx.conf.sample for Multi-Website
   - nginx.conf.sample ->  https://justpaste.it/97yki  (code)
2. Multi-Website Path : usr/share/nginx/html/giri/grocery

   - Created subfolder inside the root folder along with symbollice linksof app, lib, pub, var and copy index.php & .htaccess from root folder to subfolder
3. Inside the subfolder Symbolic Liks:

   - app,
   - lib,
   - pub,
   - var
   - index.php ->  https://justpaste.it/8a9r5  (code)
   - .htaccess ->  https://justpaste.it/1louh   (code)
4. Nginx Setup (Not sure right)

   - etc/nginx/con.d/magento.conf
   - https://justpaste.it/3xcn8 (code)
5. Site-Available setup (Not sure right)

   - etc/site-available/magento.txt
   - https://justpaste.it/1ozsu (code)

Url : http://192.168.1.64:8087/grocery (or) http://192.168.1.64:8087/gomart/grocery 404 error.

Comment: Please include the nginx error as well here.

Comment: In my case, Nginx configuration error, how to setup multi-website domain in Nginx?

Comment: check your nginx error log file  (/var/log/nginx/error.log) and post the error message here please.

Comment: Pls check with my updated post, here my doubt about how to setup Nginx?

Comment: Do you really need to setup the multisites in different directories?

Comment: This is what procedure right, if I wrong pls correct me?

Comment: Out of the box, we can run magento multi-store without having sub-directories, but it depends on your requirement. Are you planning to run all websites on the same domain or planning to use multiple domains / subdomains? How you want to structure your url etc..

Comment: @Nidheesh Any help for setup LEMP localost Multi Website url to nginx configuration? Nginx : justpaste.it/8d5xm Main website : Path - usr/share/nginx/html/gomart, URL - 192.168.1.65:8087/ Multi-website : URL - 192.168.1.65:8087/grocery/

Answer (score 2):

Can you follow below blog they have setup this.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/multi-site/ms_nginx.html

Answer (score 2):

for installation please follow the link,

[Magento 2: How to configure Nginx to use multiple websites with sub-folder](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/195175/magento-2-how-to-configure-nginx-to-use-multiple-websites-with-sub-folder)

you can also check the below link for your problem.
[Magento 2: How to configure Nginx to use multiple websites with sub-folder](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/195175/magento-2-how-to-configure-nginx-to-use-multiple-websites-with-sub-folder)

Thank You.